# file exists returns false when file exists

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    File file = new File("/stuff.txt");
    System.out.println(file.exists());
}
```

When I run it however, the `file.exists()` returns as false despite that the file exists. I checked that `System.getProperty("user.dir")` looks at the correct folder.  I think I put the files in the right place: the structure is as below:

```
-- filetest
    |-- FileTest.class
    |-- FileTest.java
    `-- stuff.txt
```

Comment: `/stuff.txt` is the absolute path from disk root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are ignoring the current `user.dir` and using the root folder `/`. To fix, remove the `/`. Like,

```
File file = new File("stuff.txt"); // <-- look for "stuff.txt" in the current folder
```